# If two cars have the same acceleration at time $t$, are the velocities of the cars the same at time $t$?

Tags: kinematics, acceleration, velocity

So when I look at the question logically, I reason that if I had two cars: Range Rover and BMW, at time t, I could pump the gas and make them accelerate at the same rate at 0.5 m/s^2 but I could be accelerating at the same rate but different speeds i.e. the Range from 100m/s and the BMW from 50m/s.

So my conclusion would be cars with the same acceleration at time $t$ could be moving at different speeds at time $t$.

Is my logic supported by any physics or is my reasoning false?

But then again for the acceleration of the BMW and Range Rover to be the same at time t, the velocity has to be the same where velocity is speed but with direction noted. Therefore, the BMW and Range Rover would have the same speed.

Comment: what you say is correct, acceleration is the rate of change in velocity, so you can have any combination of velocity and acceleration of your choice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Accelerations being equal doesn't necessarily mean that the velocities are equal, or vice versa. For example, your two cars could have the same acceleration, but if one starts before the other, the one that got going earlier wlil obviously be moving faster. An even simpler example, if one car is standing still and the other one is moving at constant speed, the acceleration is zero in both cases but the speed is different!

What is true, however, is that if the accelerations are the same *at all times* and at some point the velocities were equal, then they will remain equal forever. This is because the definition of acceleration is precisely that it is the change in velocity per unit time. If the velocities start out the same and change in the same way, they will stay equal to each other.